Did Microsoft actually release a “Critical Update Notification Tool”?
There is a commonly repeated rumour that Microsoft once released a program called the “Critical Update Notification Tool”, which they later had to quietly rename so that the acronym spell something different.  The claim is sometimes accompanied by a screenshot of this software:

If you look closely at that screenshot, though, you will notice it does not actually contain the words “Critical Update Notification Tool”.  Was this software actually named that?  Where did that name appear, if anywhere?

I wondered for a while whether this is perhaps too silly to post here, but then decided: eh, whatever.

One of my team-mates once proposed a file upgrade conversion kit utility program.

Rumour had it that a satellite sensor was going to be named the vertically aligned geostationary integrated nanosensor array... until management caught on to the little joke.

@dave Did they not consider an acronym clash with the Free University Compiler Kit?

@user3840170 The acronym for Vrije Universiteit Compiler Kit would be VUCK, though Richard Stallman is the only source I can find for that. Everywhere else calls it the Amsterdam Compiler Kit (ACK).

Similarly, the Commodore VIC-20 was sold as the VC-20 in Germany.  And FCKEditor (named for its original author Frederico Caldeira Knabben) was rebranded as CKEditor.

They also renamed the Windows Testing Framework.

Not really.  This name appeared in one Microsoft Knowledge Base article… and basically nowhere else.
The article is Q224420 from December 2000, which then was entitled “Description of the Windows Critical Update Notification Tool”.  An earlier version from July 1999 had the title “Windows Critical Update Notification Runs Every Five Minutes” and contained instructions for adjusting the frequency of notification prompts; later revisions of the article removed those, and instead told readers how to install or uninstall the program.
If you pay attention to the capitalization, you’ll notice that while “Critical Update Notification” was capitalized throughout the article, “tool” was capitalized only in the article’s title and not in the body, and does not even consistently appear after the phrase; “Critical Update Notification tool” looks like a merely descriptive phrase, and the proper name of the software was simply “Windows Critical Update Notification”.  But of course, if you put capitals in article titles for no reason, people are going to form all sorts of silly acronyms from those.
The earliest source I could find to point out the acronym was a newsletter named “Need to Know” from February 2002.  In their mini-issue from the following month, they note the phrasing was changed; and indeed, a revision of the KB article from September 2003 instead described the program as the “Windows Critical Update Notification utility”.
Since nothing seems to have changed within the software itself, the oft-repeated claim seems at best half-true.

Capitals are put on titles to conform to some style: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case

It’s a silly habit that should have been abolished long ago, just like Capitalizing every single Noun at all Times.
